# What is the asymptotic complexity of T(n) = 2T(n/3) +n/ (logn) ^2?

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

Master theorem fails so tried recursion tree, variable change, repeating method, etc etc.

I can’t handle the “sum from i = 0 to log3(n) of (2/3)^i * n/((log(n/3^i))^2 “ that occurs:

[image: photoOfSum]

Used logarithmic properties to expand, but still a dead end for me.

Comment: The Master theorem does not fail here, you just need to know that `O(log n)` is sub-polynomial.

Comment: so you mean that when I apply the master theorem I should use as "f(n) = n" (only the numerator) cause in asymptotic context it dominates the (logn)^2 in the denominator?

Comment: Kind of; I'll post as an answer later

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663818/does-the-logarithm-function-grow-slower-than-any-polynomial), a logarithm grows more slowly than any polynomial term:

[image]

Applying this result to the Master theorem, find that case 3 applies:

[image]

Hence the complexity is just

[image]